# Steam Library-Must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive, games, steam

I've looked at various questions and threads and forums on this and nothing has worked.

I've been trying to mount a HDD that I have my linux games installed to. This drive worked flawlessly in the past but now Steam needs to find it again to say these games are installed. But when I try to add the appropriate folder I get this error:

> New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute
>   permissions

I've tried changing the folder name as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554116/new-steam-library-must-be-on-a-filesystem-mounted-with-execute-permissions) and I've tried the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1668813) but run into a permission denied. Therefore I followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169073/external-hard-drive-not-allowing-permission) but am still running into permission is denied.

My question is what am I doing wrong and am I going about this correctly? How can I make steam see my games folder again? Any help is really appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and the drive location is /media/alkarin/Volume11

/dev/sdb2 is indeed ntfs

Comment: okay, I won't post as an answer as it needs some time to research, but I can give you advice for what to do*(or perhaps anybody else could elaborate)*. So, the NTFS filesystem does actually support unix-permissions. You just need to remount it with some option, and that's where you perhaps need to do some research. When you find that, and if that indeed solve the problem with Steam — you can modify the `/etc/fstab` to mount NTFS every time with the option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This `Steam` error occurs because your drive is mounted by `root` and you don't have execute permissions on the drive (I think). You can use the disks app to change this.

Search `disks` in the dash, highlight your drive and under the usage image is a small cog icon, click this and `edit mount options`, now make your settings look like this

[image]

Leave the rest as it is and reboot. Now your drive can be found in `/mnt` and is auto mounted as your user at boot.

This is how I fix this error in 14.04, NTFS drive.

Comment: That did it. Thank you! And thank you for explaining why its not working as well.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem work in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

Comment: worked on debian with ext4 drive too

Comment: This worked for me on Kubuntu. Of course I used "KDE Partition Manager" to do the task

Comment: I had to specifically set the extra mount options to `defaults,x-gvfs-show` to get it to mount with executable for Steam to load the games.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Steam requires the `exec` flag to be set. See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/725235/17810

Answer (score 7):

just got this error despite already having uid and gid set up properly as @delf answer; in my case windows left the "dirty bit", so i had to unmount it, run `sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1` where sdb1 is your disk, and remount it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I never knew that windows could leave a dirty bit on the partition. Chosen answer did not help.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For the logs: using `ntfs-3g` driver, the following minimalistic `fstab` did the trick for me

```
/dev/sdaX   /media/target-mountpoint    ntfs-3g defaults,x-gvfs-show    0   0
```

Hope that helps anyone :) Before i had forced `uid` and `gid` (to the user i was actually logged in with) and that didnt worked for some reason (i could create folders and files on the drive from a shell though, not sure what the problem was).
So the options that didnt worked:

```
defaults,permissions,users,uid=1000,gid=33
```

(Yes, my host user has www-data as primary group)

Comment: did you try the "rw"-option with the ntfs-driver?

Comment: Same situation on Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04.1) - applied this solution and it worked. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

The bug is a result of the 'users' fuse flag.
I mounted the drive with the following fstab entry:

```
UUID=DRIVEUUID   MOUNTPATH   ntfs   errors=remount-ro,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0027,fmask=0037,defaults   0 0
```

UID and GID are from my default non-root user, which I also use to start Steam as.

When you add the 'users' flag, you'll immediately get the mentioned bug.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem in Kubuntu 20.04. I am dual-booting Windows and Linux. Apparently Windows was setting the "dirty bit" as mentioned in [the answer by Lesto](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188842).

I fixed it by disabling "Fast startup" in Windows [as described here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup).