# Mount Steam Library

Tags: steam

I bought a Easystore hardrive, and I tried to select it as a new library folder but when I did it said it must be on a file system mounted with execute permissions, the file is in "var - host - media - removable." Please help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like you need to `chmod 777` the folder `removable`. Another option might be to use `sudo` to mount the drive, but (from my very limited knowledge) this can be risky due to the potential to permanently delete essential system files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam Library-Must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712451/steam-library-must-be-on-a-filesystem-mounted-with-execute-permissions)

Comment: 'man mount' please